# Unary Operator Error when I exclude multiple columns by name using pivot_longer

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data.frame of calculated means and their respective standard errors

```
    Experiment Stim      Status Treatment  Time Count CD1.CD2.Freq.Mean CD1.CD2.Freq.se
31        125   NS     Control      None  1hr     8           0.244375     0.0385273268
32        125   NS     Control      None  2hr     8           0.303000     0.0296515478
33        125   NS     Control   1,25-VD  1hr     8           0.257625     0.0344901319
34        125   NS     Control   1,25-VD  2hr     8           0.280750     0.0337827883
35        125   TT     Control      None  1hr     8           0.944375     0.0985273268
36        125   TT     Control      None  2hr     8           0.933000     0.0696515478
37        125   TT     Control   1,25-VD  1hr     8           0.127625     0.0444901319
38        125   TT     Control   1,25-VD  2hr     8           0.100750     0.0137827883
```

I am trying to use pivot_longer so I can plot multiple Freq.Mean on one ggplot. I have first removed my columns that aren't of interest (Experiment and Count).

I now need to keep columns "Stim", "Status", "Treatment", and "Time" while making new columns for my markers of interest (Example "CD1.CD2" = "Marker") and the observed value "Freq.Mean" = "Frequency" with its corresponding standard error I have calculated "Freq.se" = "se". I have more markers of interest ("CD1.CD3" separated by the same ".Freq.Mean" or ".Freq.se").

My attempt:

```
CD1.Freq.Means.125Long <- CD1.Freq.Means.125 %>%
  select(-c("Experiment", "Count"))
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c("Stim", "Status", "Treatment", "Time"),
    names_to = c("Marker"),
    names_pattern = c(".Freq.Mean", ".Freq.se"),
    values_to = c("Frequency", "se")
  )
```

I get this error:

```
Error in -c("Stim", "Status", "Treatment", "Time") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
```

I am rather new to R and StackOverflow so I apologize if I haven't provided a reproducible example quite correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% select(-c(Experiment, Count)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Stim,Status,Treatment,Time)) %>%
  mutate(name=gsub('.Freq','_Freq',name,fixed=T)) %>%
  separate(name,c('Marker','Var'),sep='_') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=value) %>%
  rename(Frequency=Freq.Mean)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Stim  Status  Treatment Time  Marker  Frequency Freq.se
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <chr> <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1 NS    Control None      1hr   CD1.CD2     0.244  0.0385
2 NS    Control None      2hr   CD1.CD2     0.303  0.0297
3 NS    Control 1,25-VD   1hr   CD1.CD2     0.258  0.0345
4 NS    Control 1,25-VD   2hr   CD1.CD2     0.281  0.0338
5 TT    Control None      1hr   CD1.CD2     0.944  0.0985
6 TT    Control None      2hr   CD1.CD2     0.933  0.0697
7 TT    Control 1,25-VD   1hr   CD1.CD2     0.128  0.0445
8 TT    Control 1,25-VD   2hr   CD1.CD2     0.101  0.0138
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Experiment = c(125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 
125L, 125L), Stim = c("NS", "NS", "NS", "NS", "TT", "TT", "TT", 
"TT"), Status = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control"), Treatment = c("None", 
"None", "1,25-VD", "1,25-VD", "None", "None", "1,25-VD", "1,25-VD"
), Time = c("1hr", "2hr", "1hr", "2hr", "1hr", "2hr", "1hr", 
"2hr"), Count = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), CD1.CD2.Freq.Mean = c(0.244375, 
0.303, 0.257625, 0.28075, 0.944375, 0.933, 0.127625, 0.10075), 
    CD1.CD2.Freq.se = c(0.0385273268, 0.0296515478, 0.0344901319, 
    0.0337827883, 0.0985273268, 0.0696515478, 0.0444901319, 0.0137827883
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("31", "32", "33", 
"34", "35", "36", "37", "38"))
```

Comment: Bananas! It worked! So just out of curiosity - do you know why I can't exclude my columns of interest based on their name, and then elongate my data based on the column header endings ".Mean" or ".se"??